# Инструментарий для исследования исходного кода

Tags: c++, ide

Подскажите, есть ли в природе такой инструментарий дающий возможность в исходном коде получить мне например выборку всех функций, классов по нужным мне критериям, например по типам аргументов или по типам возвращаемых значений определенного класса, или если касаемо классов то получить список всех объектов этого класса, родительских/дочерних классов?

Comment: Ну по типам аргументов или возвращаемых значений можно искать обычным текстовым поиском. "получить список всех объектов этого класса" - так объекты создаются при выполнении кода.

Comment: В смысле обычным поиском? Если вот к примеру мне надо получить только список функций который возвращают значение типа определенного класса, но поиск выдаст мне 1005000 строк со всеми упоминаниями данного названия класса и мне теперь тратить время выгребать по крупицам что мне именно нужно? А как быть если мне понадобится найти в каких местах и как используется  определенный метод определенного класса?

Comment: в каких местах и как наверняка можно найти нажав правой кнопки на методе и выбрам в меню "найти где используется" или типа того

Comment: Вбивайте в поиск не просто название класса, а кусок с объявлением его возвращаемым значением `-> Foo`. Хотя тогда наверное все равно остается открытым вопрос о нахождении мест, где этот класс не возвращается явно, я выводится, и об использовании в шаблонах.

Comment: Ну в контекстном меню VS я вижу только Find All References которая работает тупо как поиск, например по методу read определенного класса она мне находит все слова read во всех исходниках проекта

Comment: "по методу read определенного класса она мне находит все слова read во всех исходниках проекта" - у меня это работает, как надо @Эникейщик ¿Зачем было тег языка удалять?

Comment: @user7860670 потому что вопрос не по языку, а по IDE

Comment: @Эникейщик Так инструменты поиска зависят от языка.

Comment: Ну да, я специально плюсы поставил, чтобы мне только для питона или чего нибудь еще другого не советовали, а visual studio на всякий случай, вдруг в нем уже это реализовано как-то, а я просто не знаю как.

Comment: А где intellisense хранит свои данные которые он насканировал во всем проекте? Их извлечь никаким способом нельзя?

Comment: ну так если вопрос именно по языку, а не конкретно по VS, то не надо было в метки добавлять :) Intellij Idea правильно ищет и даже разделяет по разным группам. Вроде у них был какой-то плагин для VS, а может и есть плагин чтоб прямо в IDEA с С++ работать.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну для меня просто VS в приоритете потому что фреймворк только для неё проекты генерирует и соответственно в ней и работает, ну спасибо за подсказку, покручу IDEA на досуге

Comment: Универсальнее всего распарсить свой код libclang-ом, и там выбрать по нужным критериям.